# What's the derivative of the function $f(x)=x(sin(x))^8 $?

Tags: derivatives

I have checked the answer on wolframalpha, the answer is $(sin\,x)^7[8x\,cos\,x+sin\,x]$

But I need the explanation, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is in product form, so we use [product rule](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-1/derivative/different-rules-for-derivative/rules-for-derivative)

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))=f(x)\dfrac{d}{dx}g(x)+g(x)\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)$

Here,
$f(x)=x$

$g(x)=(sin\,x)^x$

Substitute values in formula-

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x(sin\,x)^8)=x\dfrac{d}{dx}(sin\,x)^8+(sin\,x)^8\dfrac{d}{dx}(x)$

$=(x)8(sin\,x)^7cos\,x+(sin\,x)^8$

$=8x(cos\,x)(sin\,x)^7+(sin\,x)^8$

Take $(s$$in\,x)^7$ common out,

$=(sin\,x)^7[8x\,cos\,x+sin\,x]$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the product rule. $f'(x)=8x\sin^{7}(x)\cos(x)+\sin^{8}(x)=\sin^{7}(x)[8x\cos(x)+\sin(x)]$

Answer (score 2):

The product rule says that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x) = f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
Here, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=(sin(x))^8$. Just apply the above rule.
$$f'(x) = \frac{dx}{dx} =1$$
Now apply chain rule to the function $g(x)$.
Chain rule says:
$$\frac{d}{dx}g(h(x)) = g'(h(x))h'(x) $$
In this case, $g(x) = x^8$, so $g'(x) = 8x^7$. Consequently, $h(x) = sin(x)$, so $h'(x) = cos(x)$.
Putting this all together, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(sin(x))^8 = 8(sin(x))^7cos(x) $$
$$\frac{d}{dx}x(sin(x))^8 = sin(x)^8 + 8x(sin(x))^7cos(x) = sin(x)^7(8xcos(x)+sin(x)) $$